# GraphQL data to Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query Draft {
      allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "featuredProducts" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              fixed(width: 500, quality: 100) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                originalName
              }
            }
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

I query the data with GraphQL to get some images. I try to get the output as an object so I can pass it to the Image src, using the image name as a key. I've successfully done it by map it to an array, and then convert it to an array using these methods:

```
const images = data.allFile.edges.map(image => ({
    [image.node.name]: image.node.childImageSharp.fixed,
  }))

  const arrayToObject = array => {
    return Object.assign({}, ...array)
  }

  const FeaturedProducts = arrayToObject(images)
```

I feel it's a bit too much. Is there anyway that I can get the final object without these 2 steps?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern JS (ES2019+) you can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```
const featuredProducts = Object.fromEntries(data.allFile.edges.map(edge => {
  const image = edge.node;
  return [image.name, image.childImageSharp.fixed],
}));
```

Comment: Does this still return an array? `[
    ["0", ["bilia", {
        "originalName": "bilia.png"
    }]],
    ["1", ["superloon", {
        "originalName": "superloon.png"
    }]]
]`

What I expect here is an object `{"bilia": "bilia.png"}`

Comment: @IanTran Sorry, typo fixed.